# Froala Editor doesn't delete image when cleaning the text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, froala

I use Froala to make HTML files which I store in the server. And I use the Froala module for Angular 1.

I have a button to clean the Froala editor when I add a page, but when I click on it, all images are deleted because Froala runs the event
`froalaEditor.image.removed`.

So I wondered if someone know how to block this event when I am clicking on the clean button to clean the text area of the Froala Editor?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to prevent the event from doing it's default action when you clean then area. It could be something like this

1. When you click the clean button, set a variable which tells you that the button was clicked.
2. Inside the froalaEditor.image.removed event check if the variable is true and prevent the default action.
3. After the button was clicked, set the variable back to false. Here you could use a timeout or do it on the mouseup event.